# Ordinal number on consequent values in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table like this:

```
        WITH DATA AS (
          SELECT 45 AS user_id, '2023-07-15' AS date, true AS had_session
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-16', false
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-17', true
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-18', true
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-19', true
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-20', false
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-21', true
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-22', true
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-23', false
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-24', false
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-25', false
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 45, '2023-07-26', false
        )
        SELECT *,
               -- ordinal number subquery AS consequente_counter
          FROM DATA
      ORDER BY date
```

I want to add one more column which will contain ordinal numbers for true and false. The number will start from 1 whenever the value is changed compared to the value of the previous date. Due to requirements, this has to be done in standard SQL, without using cursors or stored procedures.

**Example**

| user_id | date | had_session | consequente_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1126373 | 7/15/2023 | TRUE | 1 |
| 1126373 | 7/16/2023 | FALSE | 1 |
| 1126373 | 7/17/2023 | TRUE | 1 |
| 1126373 | 7/18/2023 | TRUE | 2 |
| 1126373 | 7/19/2023 | TRUE | 3 |
| 1126373 | 7/20/2023 | FALSE | 1 |
| 1126373 | 7/21/2023 | TRUE | 1 |
| 1126373 | 7/22/2023 | TRUE | 2 |
| 1126373 | 7/23/2023 | FALSE | 1 |
| 1126373 | 7/24/2023 | FALSE | 2 |
| 1126373 | 7/25/2023 | FALSE | 3 |
| 1126373 | 7/26/2023 | FALSE | 4 |

[Image of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zeoB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(reset, grp), 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, grp ORDER BY date) AS consequente_counter
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(reset) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
      IFNULL(had_session != LAG(had_session) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date), TRUE) reset 
    FROM DATA
  )
)
ORDER BY date
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Amazing! 

I simplified it further using more CTEs. Readability-wise, not trying to challenge a great mind here :) I can't post it in the comment unfortunately.